# TextDecoder.prototype.ignoreBOM not working as expected

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I am using fetch api to pull csv data and trying to create a csv file.

However I see that the first two characters are `ÿþ` which are BOM characters.

I however, during decoding set `ignoreBOM: true` but its not working and i always see `ÿþ` at the start of the CSV

below is my code

```
    const fetchData = await newPage.evaluate(async () => {
      let url = $('.csvLink').attr('href');
      console.log(`in here is the ${url}`);
      const stream = await fetch(url);
      let reader = stream.body.getReader();
      let receivedLength = 0;
      while(true) {
        const {done, value} = await reader.read();
        if (done) {
          break;
        }
        receivedLength += value.length;
        let v = new TextDecoder("ISO-8859-1", {fatal: false, ignoreBOM: false}).decode(value, {stream: true});
        await window.writeToStream(v, false);
      }
```

Any help to fix this would be really great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ignoreBOM` [only applies](https://encoding.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-textdecoder-encoding) for UTF-8 UTF-16BE and UTF-16LE encodings.

If you have a BOM at the beginning of your file, then it's probably not encoded as CP-1252 but rather as UTF and if that BOM is read as `ÿþ` in CP-1252, then that's probably even UTF-16LE:

```js
const littleEnd_BOM = new Uint8Array( [ 0xFF, 0xFE ] );
const as_CP1252 = new TextDecoder( 'iso-8859-1' ).decode( littleEnd_BOM );

console.log( as_CP1252 );
```

So, first thing wrong in your code is that you don't want to initialize your TextDecoder to CP-1252, but to UTF-16LE.

Now, there is some confusion about which value you did set `ignoreBOM` to, at one point you wrote you set it to `true`, while in the code snippet it's set to `false` (the default).

If you want the BOM to **stay in the output**, then set it to `true`. The parser will ignore that BOM mark, meaning it will treat it as a normal character sequence.

If on the other hand you want it to **be removed from the output**, then leave it as `false`, the parser will treat it specially, and remove it from the output.

Note that even though the BOM is here, it may not be printed from a DOMString:

```js
const UTF16LE_text = new Uint16Array(
      [ ..."\ufeffhello" ].map( (char) => char.charCodeAt(0) )
  );
// to check we really wrote a LE-BOM "FFFE"
const BOM = [ ...new Uint8Array( UTF16LE_text.buffer ).slice( 0, 2 ) ]
  .map( (v) => v.toString( 16 ) ).join('');
console.log( 'BOM:', BOM );

const ignoring_decoder = new TextDecoder( 'UTF-16LE', { ignoreBOM: true } );
const ignored = ignoring_decoder.decode( UTF16LE_text );
console.log( 'ignoreBOM:true  - text:', ignored );
console.log( 'ignoreBOM:true  - char at 0:', ignored.charCodeAt( 0 ) );

const removing_decoder = new TextDecoder( 'UTF-16LE' );
const removed = removing_decoder.decode( UTF16LE_text );
console.log( 'ignoreBOM:false - text:', removed );
console.log( 'ignoreBOM:false - char at 0:', removed.charCodeAt( 0 ) );
```

---

But an other issue you may face is that you are reading the fetched chunk of text as they come, that is by randomly sized chunk of data.
Text can't be processed this way, you need to parse it from well-defined byte position to be able to parse it correctly.

Luckily, there is a `stream` option to the `TextDecoder.decode()` method. Using it, the decoder should be able to read the stream correctly, but for this option to work, you need to store the TextDecoder outside of your while loop so it can keep the previous buffer in memory.

```
const fetchData = await newPage.evaluate(async () => {
  let url = $('.csvLink').attr('href');
  const stream = await fetch(url);
  let reader = stream.body.getReader();
  let receivedLength = 0;
  // declare the decoder outside of the loop
  const decoder = new TextDecoder("UTF-16LE");
  while(true) {
    const {done, value} = await reader.read();
    receivedLength += value.length;
    // always use the same decoder
    const v = decoder.decode(value, {stream: true});
    await window.writeToStream(v, false);
    if (done) { 
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: many thanks for your reply. I did try to set the encoding to `utf-16le` but i was seeing a lot of garbage characters when text was decoded.

Comment: When the encoding was set to `utf-16le` i do not see the BOM characters at the start any more but see a lot of garbage characters at the end of the string, something like `㈀㐀 ⌀　　㄀䠀ऀ㈀　㐀㤀㘀ऀ㈀㔀⸀㌀ऀ㈀ऀ㈀㔀⸀㌀ഀ਀�`. Not sure, what i am setting incorrectly.

Comment: Might also be UTF-8.

Comment: When i read it as UTF-8, i dont see garbage characters at the end but see the two BOM chacters, is there a way i can ignore it. like not have it considered part of the text.

Comment: can you post the first 8 values of the ArrayBuffer read from an Uint8Array?

Comment: just to confirm what you mean, after i execute ` new TextDecoder("utf-8").decode(value);` for the first time, i need to get the first 8 values, correct?

Comment: 0: 255
1: 254
2: 68
3: 0
4: 97
5: 0
6: 116
7: 0, here is what i see in the console

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215803/discussion-between-kaiido-and-opensource-developer).